# Reset dropbox automatically to first value after the users hit submit button PHP

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, concrete5

After the user hits the submit button, how do I reset the drop down menu to the "blank" option of the the menu?  I am using a MVC set up with php and HTML, and the *concrete5* library.  THANKS IN ADVANCE!  Here is what I have so far:

Controller code:

```
public function authorize() {
    $selectHost = array('' => '');
    foreach ($this->host->getHostInfo() as $row) {
        if (isset($row['HARDWARE_id'])) {
            $selectHost[$row['id']] = $row['host'];
        }
    }
    $this->set('selectHost',$selectHost);
    $postCheck=array(array('param' => 'host',
                           'check' => '^[0-9]{1,50}$',
                           'error_msg' => 'Invalid Host ID'),
    );
    $post = scrub($_POST,$postCheck);
    if (isset($post['host'])) {
        $this->host->authorize($post['host']);
        $this->set('test', "<p>  The host has successfully been authorized.</p>");
    }
    else{
        $this->set('failed', "<p>Invalid Host ID</p>");
    }
}
```

view code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?=$this->action('authorize')?>">
<?php
    $form = Loader::helper('form');
    print $form->label('host', 'Host: ');
    print $form->select('host', $selectHost);
?>
<?php   
    print $form->submit('Submit','Submit');
    echo $test;
    echo $failed;
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty positive that there's no way to override C5's desire to take the POSTed value and use that as the default. Even if, as TWR suggested, you specify a value. (This is typically a good thing, because if the page is POSTed to and there's an error, you don't want to show the value from the database; you want to show what was in the POST).

You can override the form helper pretty easily.

However, I'd suggest that you do a redirect after successful submission (don't redirect after an error -- then the POSTed value will be useful) to a page. You can redirect to another page, or the same one, ideally with a confirmation message. See https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/blob/master/web/concrete/core/controllers/single_pages/dashboard/blocks/stacks.php#L23 for an example of using redirect.

This is the best practice for your problem but also because, with your current code, if somebody hits refresh, it'll rePOST the data and reauthorize the host.

Comment: Thanks James, I'll have to look into that.  I never considered the refresh option.  I think the redirect with a confirmation message would be best.

Answer (score 0):

i think you could extend the form tag with a (javascript) onsubmit action which does the reset.

Comment: I've tried this with no luck:<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?=$this->action('authorize')?>" onsubmit="return authorize()">

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a form submit, you just want to change the value of the "drop box"/select in your view. After a submit, you'll have a fresh page load; so, in every case you'll want to display the default value, and not the current value of `$selectHost`

In your view, change this

`print $form->select('host', $selectHost);`

to this

`print $form->select('host', $selectHost, null);`

According to http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/forms/standard-widgets

Comment: No luck with that T.W.R.Cole.  I get this error message:  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/web/support.mbi.ohio-state.edu/concrete5.4.1.1/concrete/helpers/form.php on line 368. And my drop menu has no values after that.

Comment: It might have been worth mentioning that you are using "concrete5". Let me revise my answer.

Comment: Ok, Ive tried that with no luck either.  The selected option stays in the menu after I hit the submit button.  I have read all the docs on the concrete5 site without much luck either.  Thanks for the response though.  Ill keep searching and if I find solution I'll post.  Thanks!

Comment: adding this line to the beginning of the block fixed it:    $_POST['host'] = null;  thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the Concrete5 form helpers are not behaving as you want, then just don't use them -- instead just use regular HTML form inputs instead.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?=$this->action('authorize')?>">
<label for="host">Host: </label>
<select id="host" name="host">
<?php foreach ($selectHost as $value => $text): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($value); ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($text); ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<?php   
    echo $test;
    echo $failed;
?>
</form>
```